# Is this deallocation correct?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is this deallocation correct ?

vSize -> Dynamically the values will change for each and every run

// Allocation

```
int* xDump = new int(vSize);
int* yDump = new int(vSize);
```

// Deallocation

```
delete xDump;
delete yDump;
```

Is this deallocation correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Do you have any problem with it? (It seems like you have an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: The answer depends on what you do with these pointers between these two code blocks :)

Comment: Are you after *arrays* of integers? If so you should be using `new[]`, like so: `int * xDump = new int[vSize];`. Not sure what the point of this code would be, you could just store the integer directly if it's a single one.

Comment: I hardly think he really wants to dynamically allocate a single int and initialize it to something called "size"...

Comment: @every1 `int(vSize)` is this calling the constructor?

Comment: @Koushik Specifically the copy constructor. Any use of new calls some constructor.

Comment: @john copy constructor if `vSize` is integer type?otherwise?

Comment: @Koushik Well it would attempt to convert whatever type `vSize` is to an int type. or give an error if no such conversion existed.

Comment: @unwind If he's after arrays of integers, he should write `std::vector<int>` (and not worry about deallocation).  For that matter, if he shouldn't really be using dynamic allocation for an `int`, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to allocate an array of `int`s, in which case it should be:

```
int* xDump = new int[vSize];
int* yDump = new int[vSize];
```

and

```
delete [] xDump;
delete [] yDump;
```

Comment: Actually it should be: std::vector<int> xDump( vSize ); std::vector<int> yDump( vSize );

Answer (score 6):

This is correct, as long as this:

```
int* xDump = new int(vSize);
int* yDump = new int(vSize);
```

was ***not*** supposed to be this:

```
int* xDump = new int[vSize];
int* yDump = new int[vSize];
```

If you are using square brackets, you're dynamically allocating an array. In this case, you would need to use the delete[] keyword. Like so:

```
delete[] xDump;
delete[] yDump;
```

### EDIT:

If you really wanted a dynamically allocated array, it is recommended to use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), over creating one with new/delete.

For example, here's how you would use a vector in your situation:

```
std::vector<int> xDump(vSize);
std::vector<int> yDump(vSize);

// no need for delete[]
```

You should avoid owning pointers (pointers that point to memory allocated on the heap), instead try to use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), or the [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), in your code where necessary. As both [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) take advantage of the very useful [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern, which will reduce programmer errors (i.e. less chances of memory leaks) and increase exception safety.

Comment: Except that there's no scenario I can think of where `new int[vSize]` would be correct.  The way to write this in C++ is `std::vector<int> xDump( vSize );`

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I know, however, it seems that OP is learning about new/delete.

Comment: @JamesKanze the scenario in which it would be correct would be if you are making a boost shared_array<int>. You would then still use the new[] but you wouldn't do any deleting.

Comment: @miguel.martin Why?  At some point, you do have to know about `new` and `delete` in general.  But in close to 25 years of C++, I've _never_ found a case where `new[]` was a reasonable answer.

Comment: @CashCow Even then... it's the `new[]` itself which is the problem, and `boost::shared_array` doesn't do anything about that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct. No problems there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call delete [] if you intend to delete an array which does not seem to be the case here. but if parameter vSize is in square brackets [] (may be you want this?) and then you definitely should call delete []

Answer (score 0):

This construct:

```
int* xDump = new int(vSize);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int* xDump = new int;
*xDump = vSize;
```

...the answer is yes, it is correct, because you are not allocating an array.